# Possible to limit amount if items shown after a sql sort? Or not show items that have an INT less than given amount?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I apologize for wording as I'm a bit novice. Here's what I'm trying to do.

I'm using jQuery Quicksand with items that are being called from sql.

This part selects the items from the sql database, with "countout" being an INT of the number of hits out a link is getting - basically a way to sort by popularity.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `countout` DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
        echo "Database is empty";
    } else {
        while ($details = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
```

After that, I pull from the database a few things:

```
<li data-id="#<?php echo $details[1]; ?> >
     <a href="<?php echo $details[2]; ?>"> <?php echo $details[3]; ?> 
     </a>
</li>
```

With, for example, [1] being the category ID that Quicksand uses, [2] being a URL, and [3] being a site name.

The problem is that there are hundreds of items and I only want to show the top 20 or so "most popular" (items with 'countout' over 100, let's say)

Is it possible to do this? Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, you can modify your mysql query to achieve this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `countout` > 100 ORDER BY `countout` DESC LIMIT 20
```

That should give you the top 20 most popular items with countout above 100.

Comment: Excellent... does what @fabianhjr said and more.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`
ORDER BY `countout` DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Limit is the range of rows you want.

Comment: Don't worry about it, just take breath and simplify your question, then google it. For instance your query would be "I only want to show the top 20 results" with "~SQL" as a keyword. Good luck with deving and have fun. :)

Comment: Sound advice. Still, I'd rather be exhaustive than vague :)

Comment: Well, don't hesitate to ask a question here if you have issues.

Comment: It did accomplish what I wanted, except I realize now I won't be able to do additional sorts with page reloads (to pages that have different mysql sorts). I guess I'll need a javascript solution.

Comment: No you could use a LIMIT int(GET['page']) * 20, int(GET['page']) * 20 + 20

Comment: I'm sorry, would you mind clarifying? For clarification on my above comment, I meant WITHOUT* page reloads. Though I'm still uncertain of what you wrote does? Was 'page' an example or do I replace that with something?

Comment: Ok, so you want them to be able to browse several pages without reloading the page? history.js and AJAX. page is a page number, so you would move from popolar site to less popular sites if needed.